# msflexgrid Unicode

Tags: unicode, visual-c++, msflexgrid

I have an old project that I am trying to Unicode enable.  I am trying to put Unicode data into an msflexgrid, but it comes out as question marks.

Is there some trick to getting MSFlexGrid to work with Unicode data?  Will it work at all?  If not, is there a good OCX replacement that I could use?

Answer (score 2):

**Does MS Flex Grid support Unicode?**  No.

**Is there a suitable replacement?** Yes.

The MS Hierarchical Flexgrid (MSHFLXGD.OCX) appears to have the same API and supports UNICODE.  http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;275201

I have confirmed that you can send unicode data to this OCX.

**Where can I get MS Hierarchical Flexgrid?** VS6SP6.

MSHFLXGD.OCX comes with Visual Studio 6.  The latest version is 6.0.88.4, which can be found in [Visual Studio 6 Service Pack 6](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=A8494EDB-2E89-4676-A16A-5C5477CB9713&displaylang=en).

If you don't have the ancient Visual Studio 6, you can do the following:

1. Download [Visual Studio 6 Service Pack 6](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=A8494EDB-2E89-4676-A16A-5C5477CB9713&displaylang=en) (Vs6sp6.exe)
2. Extract MSHFlxGd.CAB from Vs6sp6.exe
3. Extract the contents of MSHFlxGd.CAD.
4. Install MSHFLXGD.INF by right-clicking on it and pressing install.  (This copies MSHFlxGd.ocx to c:\windows\system32)
5. ## 4 didn't register the OCX for me, so I manually called regsvr32 on the ocx.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this grid](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20183/The-Ultimate-Grid-Home-Page), or [this one](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8/MFC-Grid-control).  Neither are OCX though.  Also: you'll need to enable unicode for your project though.  Good luck!